# How to achieve page turning effect in Reflectly app in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

The transition from page 0(the `Your Stories...` stuff) to page 1 blocked me.

*what i want*

[image]

*tried with ListView + PageScrollPhysics*

[image]

*tried with PageView, Page 0 has the same extent as page 1, but it should not.*

[image]

Comment: do you need transaction in  tab view or new Screen ?

Comment: @ Viren V Varasadiya new Screen